# ReactNative Android app crash. Error while updating property padding in shadow node of type: RCTView

Tags: android, css, reactjs, react-native, mobile

This is the error I get

[image]

Few things are bugging me here.

This crash is happening at random times, in development, and when the app is built for production.

I found out that problem might be because values for properties like `padding` and `margin` are set as strings rather than integers. This is not a problem in my case, because all of them are set as integers.

I was thinking that it might be an SVG problem, but they don't have any inline style set that would cause this. Or maybe it could be something else with SVG images.

Content is loaded from WordPress using `react-native-render-html` but I don't think that this could be the problem.

I am using `"react-native": "0.63.3",`

If anyone could help me out it would be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to set padding as "20px", but it should be just 20.

So it looks like this:

```
<View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not happy with your padding attribute in the style object. Try to find that attribute and check its value is correctly set. It has to be a numeric value, not a string. Moreover, android does not accept "&"  operations in values like {padding: isValueMatched() && 10}, whereas it should be like {padding: isValueMatched() ? 10 : undefined}.